# Flutter/Dart and Firebase, How to get data in list not in realdatetime

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, real-time-data

I am creating a Flutter app that allows a list of products of a store. To practice, I have base myself in flutter firebase [example](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_database#-example-tab-):

I have managed to show a list with products stored in firebase, but my problem is that when a user adds a product, the list automatically refreshes, since it is realdatatime. The example code:

```
  new Flexible(
child: new FirebaseAnimatedList(
  key: new ValueKey<bool>(_anchorToBottom),
  query: _messagesRef,
  reverse: _anchorToBottom,
  sort: _anchorToBottom
      ? (DataSnapshot a, DataSnapshot b) => b.key.compareTo(a.key)
      : null,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,
      Animation<double> animation, int index) {
    return new SizeTransition(
      sizeFactor: animation,
      child: new Text("$index: ${snapshot.value.toString()}"),
    );
  },
),
```

),

In the code i use FirebaseAnimatedList() to load a query from firebase, it works perfectly, but when many products are added in a short time, for the user it would be very annoying.
I would like the user to refresh this manually.

I've seen that the [firebase_list](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/firebase_database/latest/ui_firebase_list/ui_firebase_list-library.html) library exists, but I can not find any example of how to use it and I do not know if it would be the solution to the problem.

Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can override [`didChangeDependencies`](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_database/lib/ui/firebase_animated_list.dart#L141) and instead of calling `setState` when a child is added, note the change with a `needsRefresh` variable for example.

```
@override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    if (widget.sort != null) {
      _model = new FirebaseSortedList(
        query: widget.query,
        comparator: widget.sort,
        onChildAdded: (_) => _needsRefresh = true, //_onChildAdded,
        onChildRemoved: _onChildRemoved,
        onChildChanged: _onChildChanged,
        onValue: _onValue,
      );
    } else {
      _model = new FirebaseList(
        query: widget.query,
        onChildAdded: _onChildAdded,
        onChildRemoved: _onChildRemoved,
        onChildChanged: _onChildChanged,
        onChildMoved: _onChildMoved,
        onValue: _onValue,
      );
    }
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for respond, forgive i am new in flutter and i don't understand very good this. I understand that you tell me to modify the flutter package and his firebase_animated_list.dart file. I've done a test, but it has not worked, i kept showing the information in real time. Based on your idea, I modified the file /ui/firebase_sorted_list.dart, in the function _onValue to execute  clear() before to onValue(event.snapshot).
It seems to work, but I do not know if it is a correct solution.

Comment: Don't modify the library, extend the class and override the method. For example, `class MyList extends FirebaseAnimatedList` and inside the class, `@override didChangeDependencies ...`. I'm on mobile so I can't say much more right now.

Comment: Ok Jacob, i understand,  FirebaseAnimatedList.dart contains class FirebaseAnimatedListState and contains didChangeDependencies(), in this case i need create class FirebaseAnimatedListState extends FirebaseAnimatedListState and override didChangeDependencies(). I go to test this. thanks